Prestashop/Dephi crear imagen para producto - error "Please set an "image" parameter with image data for value"
Estoy haciendo un conector para Prestashop versión 8.1.5 con delphi Berlin, mi problema es al intentar crear/subir la imagen de una categoría. He intentado poner los parámetros de todas las formas posibles, añadiendo la imagen tanto en params como en body, indicando el nombre de la imagen, la ruta completa, etc.... Este es mi código por si pueden darme algo de luz:
  FRESTClient := TRESTClient.Create(FBaseURL);
  FRESTClient.ContentType := 'image/jpeg';
  FRESTClient.Accept := 'application/json, text/plain, text/xml; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8';
  FRESTClient.AcceptCharset := 'ISO-8859-1, *;q=0.8';
  FRESTClient.Authenticator := THTTPBasicAuthenticator.Create(FClaveCliente,'');

  FRESTRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
  FRESTResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(nil);

  FRESTResponse.ContentType := 'image/jpeg';

  FRESTRequest.Client := FRESTClient;
  FRESTRequest.Response := FRESTResponse;
  FRESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  FRESTRequest.Resource := 'images/categories/'+FCategoriaID;
  FRESTRequest.ClearBody;
  FRESTRequest.Params.Clear;

  LStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  LStream.LoadFromFile(AFileName);
  LStream.Position := 0;

  FRESTRequest.Params.AddItem('image',extractfilename(AFileName));
  FRESTRequest.AddBody(LStream, TRESTContentType.ctIMAGE_JPEG);

  FRESTRequest.Execute;


El error dice con bastante claridad que la imagen debe ir en el parámetro imagen y tú estás enviando el nombre del archivo. Sugiero que leas la documentación del API que estás implementando, allí debe explicar en qué formato debe ir la imagen, probablemente sea en base64, pero no hay una única manera de hacerlo y los programadores de dicha API debieron haber documentado cómo lo hicieron ellos.

Puedes editar tu pregunta, por ejemplo, añadiendo la URL donde está la documentación de categorías. Lo habitual (complementando lo que ha dicho [jachguate]) es que la imagen se suba utilizando base64, es decir, convertir la imagen a base64 y añadir ese valor a un parámetro .

Convertí la imagen a base64 y sigue dando el mismo error es como si el webservice de prestashop no reciba el parámetro imagen, lo he enviado de 2 formas:  request.params.addItem('image',base64string); y como request.addparameter('image',base64string)
